# How to escape characters for JSON with Javascript

Tags: json, performance, javascript

How i can escape characters for JSON with javascript in one page?
Here is js what i need used
**bernhardhaeussner.de/odd/json-escape/** (here is text encoding after paste an click on ↓ escape ↓, but i need that text will be encode in load.)
**github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/json2.js#L211**
But i can't imagine how i can make it.
I need global code something like this.

```
<script>document.write(escape("Test code"));</script>
```

Give me example please man!:) Here is code what i have

```
{ "snippet": {  "data": "2022-02-15T23:32:01.000Z",  "data2": "2022-02-14T23:32:01.000Z",  "data3": "t3",  "data4": "test descr" }, "data": {  "status": "bxx" }}
```

After escaped code is `"{ \"snippet\": {  \"data\": \"2022-02-15T23:32:01.000Z\",  \"data2\": \"2022-02-14T23:32:01.000Z\",  \"data3\": \"t3\",  \"data4\": \"test descr\" }, \"data\": {  \"status\": \"bxx\" }}"`

How i can make it? Give please example with js. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any "escaping" for JSON; just create the structure you want to turn into a JSON string, and use `JSON.stringify` to create the string. I'd give you an example but I can't begin to see from your question *what* you're trying to turn into JSON.

`escape` is completely unrelated to JSON (or just about anything else but `unescape`).

---

Re your update:

If you have a variable containing that structure, again, just use `JSON.stringify` on it:

```
var data = { "snippet": {  "data": "2022-02-15T23:32:01.000Z",  "data2": "2022-02-14T23:32:01.000Z",  "data3": "t3",  "data4": "test descr" }, "data": {  "status": "bxx" }} ;
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: Im trying, but failing. What im doing wrong?:) jsfiddle.net/zftb7q9L/

Comment: @Jane: You don't put `<script>` tags in the jsFiddle JavaScript box: http://jsfiddle.net/zftb7q9L/1/

Comment: I check your link but i don't see anything in results  http://jsfiddle.net/zftb7q9L/1/
Can you please create new jsfiddle.net link

Comment: @Jane: Open the web console to see the result. Sorry, meant to put a note in the fiddle about that.

Comment: Thanks! Now i see it. I checked this code with what i need and famn but it dont that what i need...:( Can you please check js in site  bernhardhaeussner.de/odd/json-escape/#desc and make http://jsfiddle.net with console.log(json); please?

Comment: @Jane: To get help on SO, you need to clearly explain **on SO** what you're trying to do. If someone answers but you don't understand the answer, be precise about what you don't understand. If the answer doesn't do what you want, be precise about what you want and how the answer doesn't do that.

Comment: Sorry if i write lil bit harded:D English is not my primary language. I will try to explain more detalisied what i need:

Comment: Sorry if i write lil bit harded:D English is not my primary language. I will try to explain more detalisied what i need :

1. go to **bernhardhaeussner.de/odd/json-escape/** (check there js which working)
2.Paste code `{ "snippet": {  "data": "2022-02-15T23:32:01.000Z",  "data2": "2022-02-14T23:32:01.000Z",  "data3": "t3",  "data4": "test descr" }, "data": {  "status": "bxx" }} ` into first box.
3. Getting this code escaped and quoted from box called "Escaped & quoted:"
4. I need make code like which you give me(onload code).

Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/EhyDN17.jpg